# cassandra c# driver memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, cassandra

Using cassandra .net driver we are facing the following issue:
When inserting a lot of rows with parameterized INSERTs, the application memory usage continuously grows:

```
class Program
{
    static Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoints(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["address"])
        .Build();
    static Session session = cluster
        .Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyspace"]);
    static int counter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    new Person()
                    {
                        Name = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter).ToString(),
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Data = new byte[4096],
                    }.Save(session);
                }
            }).Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public Guid ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Save(Session session)
    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        session.Execute(session.Prepare(
            "INSERT INTO Person(id, name, data) VALUES(?, ?, ?);")
            .Bind(this.ID, this.Name, this.Data));

        Console.WriteLine("{1} saved in {0} ms",
            w.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, this.Name);
    }
}
```

According to the created memory dump the managed heap contains a huge amount of small byte arrays (most of them being generation 2), which could be traced back to the cassandra driver's byte conversion methods (InvConvert*) in the internal TypeInterpreter class.

Do you have any advice or ideas how we could get rid of this issue?

Comment: Do any of `.Prepare`, `.Bind` or `.Execute` return an `IDisposable`? If so, `Dispose` them. If not, you're out of luck and the library you're using probably has a bug.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else that runs into this.  I having memory problems when creating lots of `Cassandra.ISession`s even though I was disposing it correctly via a `using` statement.  Changing my code to reuse a single `ISession` seems to have fixed it.  I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: I am also wondering if it is the only solution since it is stated that cassandra does support connection pooling (25 by default).

Comment: According to http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra you indeed need to create one instance of `Cluster` and one for `Session` and reuse those.
Don't create a new cluster and session for every query to Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the preparedstatement for every record you are trying to insert.  Try to create the preparedstatement once as you create the session.

Answer (score 0):

try to use dispose if possible. Perhaps your Garbace Collection cannot clear them.
You also should write the developers of Cassandra. Looks like a bug for me.

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After further investigation, and storing the result of the Prepare statement in a field and reusing it the memory footprint decreased. Seems like the Cassandra library has some internal issues, will contact the developers...